# the '>' sign in defining classes

Tags: css

how can I define childs in an element with different styles?

```
#test > div[0] {
background:red;
}

#test > div[1] {
background:blue;
}

<div id="test">
<div>red bg</div>
<di>blue bg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or use a structural pseudo-class:

```
#test > div:nth-child(n)
```

but not supported by [IE or FF3](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/)

or even; (but not supported in IE6)

```
#test > div { background-color:#f00;}
#test > div + div { background-color:#0f0;}
#test > div + div + div { background-color:#00f;}
#test > div + div + div +  etc....
```

Comment: I don't think I'm 100% sure on how it works.. if I want the first and second td in a table to have background:red.. how do I then write the class? #test > tbody > tr > td + td {background:red;}

Comment: #test > tbody > tr > td { background-color: red; }

Comment: #test > tbody > tr > td + td + td { background-color: transparent; }

Answer (score 4):

You could give those elements a class:

```
#test > .red {
    background-color: red;
}

#test > .blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

<div id="test">
    <div class="red">red bg</div>
    <div class="blue">blue bg</div>
</div>
```

But note that the [child selector is not supported in IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t11).

**Update:** If you still want to support IE6 and those are the only two elements you want to apply the styles on, you can just omit the `>` (and maybe give them an ID instead of a class).

Comment: This is the best way to implement this in a cross browser fashion. If IE is not an issue you can look into the `nth-child` pseudo-selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign classes or ids to your div, depending on what is most fitting.

Alternatively, CSS3 supports [more precise pseudo classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), but you'll find those are not necessarily supported by all browsers yet.